# Better way of writing map function which is variable

Tags: javascript

I have the following script. As you can see `item.value` and `item.name` are differently. Can I write this more dynamically, easily in javascript?

```
setOptions(id, selection) {
    var options = ''
    var newArray = []

    if (selection == 'settings') {
         options = this.getStatuses(id);
         newArray = options.map(item => { return { id: item.id, text: item.value } });
    } else if (selection == 'route' && id == 'profiles') {
         options = this.getProfiles;
         newArray = options.map(item => { return { id: item.id, text: item.name } });
    }
    return newArray
}
```

Comment: You can do destructuring and inside the return function you map the array

Comment: You can use a variable with either `"value"` or `"name"` and dynamic property access (`item[propName]`), like this: `const newArray = options.map(item => ( { id: item.id, text: item[propName] } ));`

Comment: Side note: In new code, don't use `var`, use `let` or `const`. And there's no reason to assign a value to a variable (the initializers you have on `options` and `newArray`) when you're just going to overwrite it with a different value a moment later without using it in the meantime.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder can you provide me an example in total?

Comment: See https://pastebin.com/GSr5YXfF

Comment: var contacts = [{ "ContactId" : "1", "ContactName" : "Bob" },{ "ContactId" : "2", "ContactName" : "Ted" }];
    var sites = [{ "SiteId" : "1", "Location" : "MN" },{ "SiteId" : "2", "Location" : "FL" }];

    function convertResponse(response, text, value) {
      return $.map(response, function(it) {
        return {
          value: it[value],
          text: it[text]
        };
      });
    }
    
    var convertedContacts = convertResponse(contacts, 'ContactId', 'ContactName');
    var convertedSites = convertResponse(sites, 'SiteId', 'Location');

Comment: @T.J.Crowder works perfect. Thanks!